# APC doesn't free memory

Tags: php, apc

Since I installed the APC and am using it for a file upload with progress display, the memory use of my server exploded, it seems that every uploaded file keeps in the memory forever.

Answer (score 2):

That's the problem with "persistent" caches.... they're persistent.

You can set a "timeout" for APC entries when you store the entry, or you can manually remove any entry when it is no longer required. APC will also be cleared if the server is restarted.

In this case, you should probably remove the entry in your upload handling code.

Comment: i just tried to restart the server - it didnt help. i also tried apc_clear_cache(); from php, nothing either. the memory usage stays the same.

Comment: Use apc.php to see what's stored in APC cache. If a server restart doesn't clear APC... then you have a unique problem, because APC cache is using Apache's memory... and if restarting Apache doesn't clear it's memory, then either you're not caching in the way you think you are, or you haven't restarted Apache.

Comment: How are you measuring "memory usage"? Note that APC upload monitoring doesn't store any file in memory, simply a few bytes showing the size of the file.

Comment: Well, i can see the ram-usage in the control panel from my hosting provider, its about 80% now, and it increases everytime i upload a file..

Comment: RAM usage will increase while a file is uploaded... but APC uses a fixed maximum amount of memory that is pre-allocated in php.ini, and set the first time a PHP script is run after the webserver is restarted... that pre-allocation won't change. You can see exactly what proportion of that memory is used, and by what content, using apc.php

Comment: PHP itself will free all memory that it has used when the script terminates. You can see how much memory PHP uses during execution of a script with  Brazilian Portuguese Chinese (Simplified) French German Japanese Polish Romanian Persian Spanish Turkish Other  memory_get_usage() and memory_get_peak_usage().

Comment: Allright, i just did. Seems like the apc isnt the problem, it says "Used: 337.3 KBytes", but the memory usage still goes up with every uploaded file..

Comment: If memory is not being freed after the script terminates, what external programs might you be running as part of your upload process? Are you (for example) using imagemagick or similar to resize images?

Comment: Then it's likely that something other than PHP is running on the server, and using memory... linux or wintel?

Comment: It is a debian server, and the sum of the memory use of all running processes is only about 15%, while the overall memory use is 80,9%. After killing the apache2 process the memory use is back to normal.

Comment: There are a few reports of memory problems with various versions of apache on debian (eg. http://www.mail-archive.com/debian-apache@lists.debian.org/msg09130.html) don't know if any of these might be affecting you!